# spyOn is not mocking a function correctly

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am triny to test the 'else' path of this function:

```
    function incrementCounter(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if(this.momentArray.length > 0) {
            //IF PATH OMITTED
        }
        else {
            console.log("ELSE");
            initializeView().then(function(moments) {
                deferred.resolve(moments);
            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject();
            });
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

Here is my test:

```
it('Should call incrementCounter momentArray is NOT populated', function() {
    console.log("UN POPULATED");
    service.momentArray = [];
    spyOn(service, "initializeView").and.callFake(function() {
        console.log("TEST");
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve("MOCK");
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    service.incrementCounter().then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
    expect(service.initializeView).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // $scope.$apply();
});
```

I would like to mock out the 'initializeView function call.  The test should pass if the initializeView function was called since that would prove that it went down the correct path.

The expect keeps failing claiming the function is not being called.  I put a console log in the initializeView function and that log is being logged out:

```
   function initializeView() {
    console.log("INITIALIZE VIEW");
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //Omitted
    };
```

This tells me that somehow 'initializeView' is not being mocked for some reason.  Does anyuone know what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

Adding scope.$apply and making the function asynchronous.

```
it('Should call incrementCounter momentArray is NOT populated', function(done) {
    console.log("UN POPULATED");
    service.momentArray = [];
    spyOn(service, "initializeView").and.callFake(function() {
        console.log("TEST");
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve("MOCK");
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    service.incrementCounter().then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
    expect(service.initializeView).toHaveBeenCalled();
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: You're never calling $apply() to actually resolve the promise (you also ignore the fact that when() and chaining exist, BTW). Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/06/04/angularjs-promises-2/

Comment: You could try just returning [`$q.resolve("MOCK")`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#resolve) in your mock.

Comment: Are you writing a test or code? What has $scope.$apply got to do with the test? What is it that you wish to test?

Because for a branch to be tested, the function must be aware of the branch logic, which it seems not to know, It looks like it determines the branch logic by itself in which case how can you expect an external entity to test it? 

increment counter based on what? If this is known to the module that the function resides in then include the module in your test.

Comment: "incrementCounter" is probably misnamed.  I used to keep a counter but now I don't.  I basically have a stack of cards and this function checks to see if the stack is empty when the user swipes.  If it is empty it will go to the else path (The path I am trying to test).  So it should call 'initializeView' which will create a new stack.  In the test I create an empty array and then call the function - I would just like to make sure it goes down the correct path.  I would like to mock out 'initializeView' as I can test that separately.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  For whatever reason in my service code when I call a function from the same module I have to 'this'.  So in my incrementCounter() function the else should read 'this.initializeView()' and not 'initializeView()'.

If someone can explain to me why this is the case that would be great - Otherwise I hope this helps someone out.